# htaccess error with regex

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect to a page based on a regex expression.

Basically, product codes are made up of numbers and letters, nothing else.

Here is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,3})-(\d{1,3})$ search.php?q=$1&p=$2&m=$3&c=$4

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9])$ product.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

It is the last line I can't seem to get to work. It just gives me a 404 page not found error. I know for a fact that the product.php file is there, and it is in the same place as search.php which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]*)$ product.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

I guess the * matches infinite times on whats before it.

I found out because if I just went to /e, /E or /8 it would work.

Comment: it is better to match ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ so you do not get the empty string as root

Comment: Thanks! I was just battling that problem!